# How to get the last process that modified a particular file?

Tags: node.js, file

Ηi,

Say I have a file called `something.txt`. I would like to find the most recent program to modify it, specifically the full path to said program (eg. `/usr/bin/nano`). I only need to worry about files modified while my program is running, so I can add an event listener at program startup and find out what program modified it when my program was running.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a good idea. The file can be modify this 1000 programms in shello builtin commands like echo "Hello World!" > something.txt

Comment: @Thomas I don't understand, what do you mean?

Comment: Not sure about what the process name are used for, common use case would be: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch

Comment: If you worry that your file is modified externaly, it is not enough to monitor if one programm is run, because the file can modifed by many programms, you must also monitor each bash. Next problem is, that you must also monitor if this process open your file. When you using Linux as OS I think the better solution is to use inotify to monitor your file

Comment: @Xlee that package didn't work

Answer (score 1):

auditd in Linux could perform actions regarding file modifications

See the following URI xmodulo.com/how-to-monitor-file-access-on-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

Something like this generally isn't going to be possible for arbitrary processes. If these aren't arbitrary processes, then you could use some sort of network bus (e.g. redis) to publish "write" messages. Otherwise your only other bet would be to [implement your own filesystem using FUSE](https://github.com/mafintosh/fuse-bindings). Even with FUSE though, you may not always have access to the pid depending on who/what is writing to the file and the security setup of your OS.